# Gmail API - Access api without login PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to make a project which fetches mails from Gmail API in PHP.
Here is what I followed ([Gmail quickstart PHP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php.)), converted the CLI functionality for browser compatibility.

Everything is set up for fetching specific emails.  However when I do this, it asks for User Authentication and Authorization every time.   I have Email Ids and passwords of all the users and I want to authenticate them behind the scenes without the user having to do anything.

Is there any way that I can do that? I have tried googling and read many posts on StackOverflow but in the end, everyone said that we can't do it without actually authenticating from the user.

Comment: You can use a service account and give the app permission to those user accounts.

Comment: @ADyson service accounts and gmail only work with gsuite domain accounts.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to authenticate to a google api using login and password this is called client login and was shut down around 2018

In order to access private user data you need the permission of that user, in order to ask the user you can use Oauth2 and request permisson there which you are doing.

If this is a Gsuite domain account then you could also use a service account and set up domain wide dedication in order to allow the service account to impersonate a user on the domain.   Again this will only work with gsuite domain accounts not with standard gmail accounts.

You could also try the IMAP server which would allow you to login with user name and password assuming the user does not have 2fa enabled.

In any event you may want to start the process for verification of this app soon it can be quite a process.